# Can the Client Requests coming from the client machine itself handled by java on the server?

Tags: java, linux, ftp

Let me take an example to explain what I want...

There is a server machine which is running some java code to handle client requests.

**Say, for an ftp connection**

Client goes to the command prompt and types:
ftp serverip

On my Server machine this ftp request should be handled by java. Is it possible by any means?? Because all the tutorials I have seen till now talk about there is a java file for Client and a java file for Server. But I don't want any java file for Client because Client is free to access my ftp connection using command prompt in case of windows or terminal in case of linux and my server is running server socket on port 21 to address this client request and do appropriate response for each client request. But it is only able to get the ip address of the client and not letting the user to enter any username and password to enter into the vsftp. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Socket Server listening on a port, say 8080, this means that a client application that wants to connect to your server should open a Socket connection specifying the remote address of your server and the port 8080.

Now if the question is how to build an application that can be operated with the terminal this should be addressed with libraries like [Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Or you can also try to contact your server with `telnet` like

```
telnet IP_ADDR 8080
```

So the important part to understand is that you need an application client built on whatever language that opens a socket connection with your server.

Comment: Please can you tell me, if I don't want Client to use application, if that user just directly types telnet ip_addr 8080, doesn't it mean that when the user presses enter key after typing the command, in this process a socket connection from the client machine will be opened to my server? I just don't want client to use any application. The client just types the command in his command line interface in his/her machine and my server which is listening via java sockets is able to handle client request whether it is telnet or ftp...